# SelectedValue for ComboBox not getting set

Tags: c#, winforms

I have comboBox name as `cmbContactType`. I binded this combo with dataSource as DisplayMember `ValueName`(string type) and valueMember as `ValueID`(number type). When user change value in cmbContactType then cmbContactType.SelectValue get set and I am able to save document with this Selectedvalue. I facing problem while setting cmbContactType value from database which is of type number. Every time I am trying to set value, `null` value set to the `cmbContactType.SelectValue`.
Following is the code by which I am binding datasource to `cmbContactType` and for setting SelectedValue of `cmbContactType`. I am using VS2010 and MS-Access. Please help.

```
    //method to bind dataSource.
    public static void BindDataSourceWithCombo(ref ComboBox cmb, string query, string valueMember, string displayMember)
    {
        DataTable _tableSource = (new AccessConnectionManager()).GetDataTableBySQLQuery(query);

        var _dataSource = (from DataRow _row in _tableSource.Rows
                           select new
                           {
                               ValueMember = _row[valueMember],
                               DisplayMember = _row[displayMember].ToString()

                           }).ToList();

        cmb.DisplayMember = "DisplayMember";
        cmb.ValueMember = "ValueMember";
        cmb.DataSource = _dataSource;
    }

    // Method to set values in document.
    public void SetDocumentProperties()
    {
        string _query = string.Format("Select ContactCode,ContactName,ContactType from ContactMaster where ContactCode = '{0}'", Convert.ToString(cmbContactCode.Text));
        DataTable _table = AccessConnectionManagers.GetDataTableBySQLQuery(_query);

        if (_table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow _row = _table.Rows[0];
            txtContactCode.Text = Convert.ToString(_row["ContactCode"]);
            txtContactName.Text = Convert.ToString(_row["ContactName"]);
            cmbContactType.SelectedValue = _row["ContactType"];
        }
        else
        {
            txtContactCode.Text = string.Empty;
            txtContactName.Text = string.Empty;
            cmbContactType.SelectedValue = 1;
        }
    }
```

Here is code by which I bind dataSource with cmbConactType. This method call on Form_Load event.

```
    private void LoadContactTypeCombo()
    {
        //Table: PicklistValues(ID,MasterID,ValueID,ValueName) 
        string _query = string.Format("select ValueID,ValueName from PicklistValues where MasterID = {0}", 1);
        BindDataSourceWithCombo(ref cmbContactType, _query, "ValueID", "ValueName");
    }
```

Comment: first check if _row["ContactType"] is having any value. If yes then try casting it to int before assigning it to SelectedValue

Comment: Yes, `_row["ContactType"]`  has value. I tried `_row["ContactType"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(_row["ContactType"]) : -1` this also. But wasnt work.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar what is the datasource of `cmbContactType`?

Comment: @King King, Yes check dataSource. It has 6 values with Display member and valueMember

Comment: @AnkushMadankar I don't see you assign some `DataSource` to your `cmbContactType` anywhere in your code. It's important to solve your problem.

Comment: @King King, Added code which bind DataSource.

Comment: now check my post i have edited

Comment: You don't need the `ref` keyword.

Comment: @siride Yes it is true.. here method argument is of reference type. Learning mistakes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution to my question, when I look for Type of cmbContactType.SelectedValue, I found it is typeof Int16...! and by using following statement cmbContactType.SelectedValue get set.

`cmbContactType.SelectedValue =_row["ContactType"] != null ? Convert.ToInt16(_row["ContactType"]) : (Int16)(-1) ;`

Answer (score 3):

try by this method

```
int index;
// Search the Item that matches the string
index=cmbContactType.FindString(_row["ContactType"]);
// Select the Item in the Combo
cmbContactType.SelectedIndex=index;
```

Comment: I dont find `FindByValue` method for both `cmbContactType` and `cmbContactType.Items`

Comment: No. Its window's default ComboBox tool.

Comment: `index` get -1 value. Hence no value get set in cmbContactType. Actually _row["ContactType"] has int value and FindString required string value so `index` get -1 value.

Comment: can u get the Display member text instead of value member???in your query,this would solve your problem

Comment: or if it is display member only then convert that int value tostring

Answer (score 3):

You should notice the type of the actual `ValueMember` in your `DataSource`, when assign the `SelectedValue` to some value, it should be castable to the type of the actual `ValueMember` in your DataSource.

You have to ensure that `_row["ContactType"]` has to be contained by the item values of your `cmbContactType`. If not, the `SelectedItem` will be null. You should perform some check and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried this also. See `_dataSource` it has `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` , And I bind this DataSource to combo so I need to pass same Value and Display member which `_dataSource` has. e.g. `valueMember` may have value like "Name" and `displayMember` may have value "ID".. Isn't it?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar originally you passed the fixed strings `"DisplayMember"` and `"ValueMember"` to your `cmb.DisplayMember` and `cmb.ValueMember`, you have to pass in the parameters `displayMember` and `valueMember` instead, that's what it should be. You still have problem? Is it still the same as before?

Comment: Yes, When I change my code as mention in ur answer, I am getting now `cmbContactType.Text` as
"{ ValueMember = 1, DisplayMember = Company }" (By Immediate Window).. that means cmbContactType dont have proper Value and Display members. Binding have fixed value "DisplayMember" and "ValueMember" bcos `_dataSource` have same values.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar OK, I overlooked the datasource you prepare before. You should check the value of `_row["ContactType"]`, I can see that your combobox has value member of `ValueID` but when you assign its `SelectedValue`, you use a `_row["ContactType"]`? That could be your problem.

Comment: DataType of ValueID was the problem..! It is Int16 and I am casting it as Int32, Now my problem get solved. Thanks for ur positive responses.